# Auto completion in RStudio stops working properly after first use of train() function from caret package

Tags: autocomplete, rstudio, r-caret

The tile says it all. Once I run the train function from the caret package, the tab auto complete in RStudio no longer displays the available function arguments (pink icons) and mydata$ + tab does not show the available columns in mydata data frame.

Here are the auto completion options before I run the train function:

[image: auto completion options before I run train ex1 image]

... and here are the auto completion options after the train function was run:

[image: auto completion options after I run train ex1 image]

Has anyone else experienced this issue? Is this a known bug? Is there a workaround?

Thanks.
LG

Comment: This seems a little off-topic for this site.  You might try on an RStudio forum or bug tracker?

Comment: Should be fixed with the latest version 0.99.896.